# Get text between several tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this html code on page:

```
<div style="display:none" id="roles">
        <span>Manager</span>
        <span>Seller</span>
</div>
```

And i jas want to get array of string between spans element.

```
var roles = document.getElementById("roles").innerText.match("what i should get here"); // output roles = ["Manager", "Seller"]
```

Comment: Why regex? Use DOM: `document.querySelectorAll('#roles > span')`

Comment: Split the string by newline, then use `<span>(.*?)</span>` to match the content of each `<span>` tag, should a given line contain one.

Comment: before embarking down the rabbit hole of regex+html - say hello to [tony the pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate `span` elements and get its text.

```js
//Get the span elements
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("#roles span");
var roles = [];

//Iterate the elements
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  //fetch textContent and push it to array
  roles.push(spans[i].textContent);
}

console.log(roles)
```

```html
<div style="display:none" id="roles">
  <span>Manager</span>
  <span>Seller</span>
</div>
```

You can also use as suggested by [@Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar)

```js
//Get the span elements
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("#roles span");
var roles = Array.from(spans).map(s => s.textContent);
console.log(roles)
```

```html
<div style="display:none" id="roles">
  <span>Manager</span>
  <span>Seller</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar `Array.from(spans).map(s => s.textContent);`

Comment: looks very simple and powerful. Thanks @Tushar

Comment: @nickzdravcov And new too, check the browser/env support before using it.

Answer (score 7):

```js
var roles = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('roles').getElementsByTagName('span')).map(function(node) {
  return node.innerText || node.textContent;
});

console.log(roles);
```

```html
<div style="display:none" id="roles">
  <span>Manager</span>
  <span>Seller</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Get all span elements using **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** then convert it to array with help of **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** method(older browser use [`[].slice.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) and now generate  the result array using **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method.

```js
// for older browser use `[].slice.call(...` instead of `Array.from(...`
var res = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#roles span')).map(function(e) {
  return e.textContent;
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<div style="display:none" id="roles">
  <span>Manager</span>
  <span>Seller</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="exmpl1">   
<span id="1st"> A1</span>
<span id="2nd"> A2</span>
<span id="3rd"> B1</span>
<span id="4th"> B2</span>
<span id="5th"> C1</span>
</div>

var spans = document.getElementById('exmpl1').getElementsByTagName('span'),
obj = {};

for (var i = 0, j = spans.length; i < j; i++) {
    obj[spans[i].id] = spans[i].textContent || spans[i].innerText;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first finding the descendents of the roles `div` and then iterating through them in a `for` loop to post the results to an array.

```
    //Define the parent div
    var parent = document.getElementById('roles');

    //Find the children of the parent div
    var children = parent.getElementsByTagName('span');

    //Count how many children there are within the parent div
    var totalChildren = children.length;

    //Declare a new array to store the roles in
    var rolesArray = [];

    //And let the for loop push each role into the array
     for (var i = 0; i < totalChildren; i++) {
        rolesArray.push(children[i].innerText);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution :

```
var spans;  
document.querySelectorAll('#roles > span').forEach(function(element){
        spans.push(element.textContent);
 });
```